# Memory Allocation Error - SKAction runBlock (malloc error)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, malloc

I am getting a memory error when attempting to run an action block, I have googled it a few times and I cannot work out what is wrong?

```
//[self newSquareAt:location];

[self runAction:[SKAction runBlock:^{
    [self newSquareAt:location];
}]];
```

The uncommented line of code works ok and no error or memory allocation problems

yet when i try to run the SKAction, i get the following error:

malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1048576) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region

please help

Comment: why has my post been edited? changing I have to I've? what is the point of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be malloc being unable to allocate more memory. The way iOS works, I suspect you only get this message if you allocate lots of memory very quickly, because normally you would get a message that you are running out of memory.

Run your code under Instruments and find out where you are allocating tons of memory.

Comment: I have run it in instruments, it keeps allocating memory for SKCAction and SKRunBlock. Is it stuck in a loop? just keeps allocating memory.. but why?